# Screen size is too big and moves

Tags: screen, settings

After my daughter touched the pc now my screen size  of the desktop is too big. Resolution of Ubuntu and monitor is correct on 1920*1080.
Tried all settings from the screen settings menu as well as of the monitor.
when I move the mouse left, the screen moves right, very annoying.

Comment: Try to look into "Settings > Accessibility > Zoom". Next time you provide the version and Ubuntu flavor. E.g. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS or Kubuntu 20.04 etc.